# Add-RecipientPermission gives back ok result but SendAs rights are not set when queried by Get-RecipientPermission

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, hybrid, rights-management

I am trying to set the Send-As rights on a synced user in a Hybrid Exchange environment. I stored all the onPrem SendAs rights data in a SQL database, and i am looping that database to set the Send-As in the cloud using Add-RecipientPermission, as Microsoft does not sync that.

Part off my code is as follow:

```
foreach ($userToProcess in $dtUsersToProcess) {

        $userId = $userToProcess["UserId"]
        $delegateTo = $userToProcess["DelegateTo"]
        $primarySmtpAddress = $userToProcess["PrimarySmtpAddress"]
        $delegateToSmtpAddress = $userToProcess["DelegateToSmtpAddress"]

        # Process each record
        $logger.Debug("Processing user: $userId ($primarySmtpAddress) to give delegation to $delegateTo ($delegateToSmtpAddress).")

        try {
          $result = $NULL
          $result = Add-RecipientPermission -Identity $primarySmtpAddress -Trustee $delegateToSmtpAddress -AccessRights sendas -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
          $message = "On user $($result.Identity) the trustee $($result.Trustee) has AccessContyrolType $($result.AccessControlType) and IsValid $($result.IsValid) with AccessRights $($result.AccessRights)."
          $userToProcess.RightSet = 1
          $userToProcess.FeedBack = $message
          $logger.Info($Message)
        }
        catch [System.Management.Automation.WarningRecord] {
          $message = "Warning for $userId and $delegateTo : $($_.Exception.Message)."
          $userToProcess.RightSet = 1
          $userToProcess.FeedBack = $message
          $logger.Warning($message)
        }
        catch {
          $message = "Add-RecipientPermission for $primarySmtpAddress to $delegateToSmtpAddress was not ok: $($_.Exception.Message)."
          $userToProcess.RightSet = 0
          $userToProcess.FeedBack = $message
          $logger.Error($message)
        }
        $rowCount++
```

Now I notice in my log files following

Set-SendAsRights;Processing user: u****3 to give delegation to user1.
Set-SendAsRights;On user u****3 the trustee user1 has AccessContyrolType Allow and IsValid True with AccessRights SendAs.
Set-SendAsRights;Processing user: u****3 to give delegation to user2.
Set-SendAsRights;On user u****3 the trustee user2 has AccessContyrolType Allow and IsValid True with AccessRights SendAs.
Set-SendAsRights;Processing user: u****3 to give delegation to user3.
Set-SendAsRights;On user u****3 the trustee user3 has AccessContyrolType Allow and IsValid True with AccessRights SendAs.
Set-SendAsRights;Processing user: u****3 to give delegation to user4.
Set-SendAsRights;On user u****3 the trustee user4 has AccessContyrolType Allow and IsValid True with AccessRights SendAs.
Set-SendAsRights;Processing user: u****3 to give delegation to user5.
Set-SendAsRights;On user u****3 the trustee user5 has AccessContyrolType Allow and IsValid True with AccessRights SendAs.
Set-SendAsRights;Processing user: u****3 to give delegation to user6.
Set-SendAsRights;On user u****3 the trustee 12434309-1b53-4536-b6d2-2a94c284eaa4 has AccessContyrolType Allow and IsValid True with AccessRights SendAs.

But when I execute Get-RecipientPermission I see that not all rights have been set, although Add-RecipientPermission told me it did.

```
PS C:\Users\myUser> Get-RecipientPermission -Identity u****3

Identity Trustee                      AccessControlType AccessRights Inherited
-------- -------                      ----------------- ------------ ---------
u****3 NT AUTHORITY\SELF    Allow             {SendAs}     False
u****3 user1@blabla.com     Allow             {SendAs}     False
u****3 user4@blabla.com     Allow             {SendAs}     False
```

So the big question is why the Add-RecipientPermission returned a valid result ?

I executed the commands from the script manually, and there it was not a problem

```
$result = Add-RecipientPermission -Identity u****3 -Trustee user1 -AccessRights sendas -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
$result = Add-RecipientPermission -Identity u****3 -Trustee user2 -AccessRights sendas -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
$result = Add-RecipientPermission -Identity u****3 -Trustee user3 -AccessRights sendas -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
$result = Add-RecipientPermission -Identity u****3 -Trustee user4 -AccessRights sendas -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
$result = Add-RecipientPermission -Identity u****3 -Trustee user5 -AccessRights sendas -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
$result = Add-RecipientPermission -Identity u****3 -Trustee user6 -AccessRights sendas -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
```

A Get-RecipientPermission returned all results as expected.

Comment: How long did you wait before checking? Maybe interactively was enough time to reflect? Just a thought because otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: More the 20 hours. And is very intermittent. I looped all my users that were set with Get-RecipientPermission and stored those in a database. When I  compare both tables, I see that I have set 12575 trustees, but Get-RecipientPermission table only sees 12456. So i do have a success rate of 99%. Strange indeed.